# "in" operation in Python

Tags: python

so I am a JavaScript developer, and I'm learning python for ML. And im going through some different courses on Python, and I encountered some weird thing with "in" operator, that I can't find an explanation for.

So for example I have a list this_list = [1,2,3,4] and if I do print(True in this_list) I should get a False. But instead I get True. Ok so maybe it's checking for truthy values. But if I do the same with ["bananas', "apples'] list I get False. So maybe someone who has experience with Python can explain to me the logic behind this operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has less to do with `in` than it does with the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int`. `True` is equal to `1`, which is all the `in` operator cares about. (That is to say, `in` uses equality, not object identity, here*.)

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
>>> True == 1
True
>>> True in [1, 2, 3]
True
>>> 1 in [True, False]
True
```

---

* In general, `x in c` is implemented with `c.__contains__(x)`, so it really depends on how a given container defines its `__contains__` method whether or not equality is used. In this case, `list.__contains__` does use equality.

Comment: It uses both identity and equality, not only equality